# how does mavlink or any other over-the-air protocol come in play with software?

Tags: java, dji-sdk, mavlink, 3dr

I'm trying to understand how one software such as Mission Planner or APM2 or QGroundControl works from beginning to end.
So, each application/software source code does not directly execute passing mavlink protocols, correct?
Are the mavlink protocols embedded in the library packages, which are being used in the program?
If so, I still can't find any mavlink protocol on each command, such as isArmed() or isConnected(), in the library source code.
Essentially, I want to create my own java library with mavlink so that I can create my own ground control station software which is not tracked by a company, such as DJI.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you'll find [dronefleet/mavlink](https://github.com/dronefleet/mavlink) useful. It allows reading/writing mavlink messages and provides an abstraction layer from the low-level stuff.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this library.